# How to open and close navigation drawer click on custom action bar icon in Android?

Tags: android

Im beginner in Android app developement. I have implement custom action bar in Android app.I have add 2 images on custom action baar see below xml code

```
    custom.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/black_pattern" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And set this xml file in actionbar view

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
            mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

            View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
            TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
            mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

But right now i want to open and close the navigation drawer on imageButton  click which included in custom.xml layout and add in action baar. I implement navigation drawer also , but i don't understand how to show and hide navigation drawer on  imageButton click event.Can someone help how to do this

Im trying this way

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = "test";

        mPlanetTitles = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try call drawerLayout.openDrawer(int gravity) on image button click?

Comment: No , but tried another way . Can you see in my above post .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have the navigation drawer implemented you can try:

```
NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, mDrawerLayout);

ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END))
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                    else
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
                }
            });
```

Comment: And for compatibility version: 
   if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }

Comment: How is your xml? Is `NavigationDrawerFragment` native?

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawer layout

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<!-- List of Actions (pages) -->


     <ListView android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:layout_width="280dp"
      android:id="@+id/navList"
      android:background="#ffffffff"
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
      android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"/>
     </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



  private DrawerLayout drawer;
    // DrawerLayout
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    Add the drawer content to the listview
    and use
    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    To open and close the drwaer on imge click
```

Comment: http://codetheory.in/android-navigation-drawer/ there is a custtome navigation drawer example in that link ans that is working fine you can edit it easy with your wish

Comment: In your code you can use mDrawerLayout .openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT) to open the nav drawer on any even in that activty :)

Comment: Akariuz Answer will fine for you :)